# Is it possible to encrypt only certain data when a laptop hibernates?

Tags: windows-8.1, encryption, truecrypt, hibernate, pgp

I would like to achieve protection from both ends of the spectrum:

On the one end you have the need to protect the sensitive data on the laptop. Encryption of the system disk means the data will be secured when the laptop is closed (providing it is configured to hibernate).

On the other end however you have a totally inexperienced thief, who would just use the laptop without formatting/resetting to factory settings (or sell it to a similarly inexperienced user). In which case it might be possible to recover the laptop using the likes of Prey.

The problem with full system disk encryption is that the chance (although small) of recovering the laptop is completely lost as the thief will be forced to find someone who can format the laptop for them.

Is there a reasonably* secure way of securing memory belonging to some processes when the laptop (win 8.1) hibernates, but where the laptop would still be usable if the decryption pass phrase was not known? (Or anything of this sort, e.g. the laptop could be started normally if a 'hibernation recovery password' was not known.)

The requirement is simply that when the laptop is opened, some of the memory belonging to certain active processes is not available without a password, and of course that the volume encryption key used is no longer available.

I would not like to close down all the programs I am using and dismount the encrypted volume every time I stop using the laptop. This would be too time consuming.

(*The data I would like to protect is just work related, so I am not too worried about specialist techniques being used to recover memory that's not obvious on the screen, i.e. via open applications. Similarly, a thief could potentially snatch the laptop without closing it and thus have full access to the protected volume, but I am happy to chance this ;)

I have not yet decided on which hard disk encryption software to use (TrueCrypt, PGP, BitLocker), so if any of these has a clever feature that would overcome the problem described, I would be very grateful to know.

Thank you in advance for any input and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

When the PC hibernates, the memory is written to a file on disk, as long as your disk is fully encrypted, this is relatively safe. However, typically, your PC does **not** hibernate immediately unless you have changed the default settings, it goes to sleep. In that state all of the memory is still live. In theory this memory can be recovered. In practice, this requires highly specialised equipment and knowledge and is unlike to be a threat to you or your work information unless you work with highly sensitive data worth a 3rd party accessing. In that case, you should be given specialist equipment and instructions on safety & security.

So you cannot protect parts of the memory in the way you describe. You would have to ensure that you had closed applications that access the data you want to protect. If you were concerned about the laptop when it is asleep. You would also need to make sure the temporary files and the page file are cleared.

Once the laptop hibernates, the active RAM is unpowered. There is a small window of opportunity for a well funded attacker to recover that but again, not worth worrying about for most people.

Once hibernated, all data is on disk which is why full disk encryption is required by all sensible organisations that have staff using laptops with sensitive data.

If you have a modern PC with Windows Pro or Enterprise, Bitlocker is certainly the way to go as it is integrated into the OS. For older PC's or for use with Windows Home/std, Veracrypt or Truecrypt is good. There are 3rd party commercial tools too.

One word of caution regarding full disk encryption though. If you have a disk error, it is perfectly possible to get into a situation where you cannot recover any of the data from the disk. Back it up!!

I really wouldn't even think about trying to recover a laptop once stolen. You would be relying on someone turning on the laptop somewhere where it can connect to the Internet (mainly that would require a wired connection) or where the new "owner" had broken into your login. The latter is very worrying since you really cannot ever garentee that there are not files or data lying around that you don't want exposed (e.g. your calendar, friends and colleagues contact details and locations, etc.). Protect the whole thing and look after it so that the only risk is being mugged.

Comment: I did specifically write "providing it is configured to hibernate", but nevertheless thank you for your answer. (I would vote it up, but the website informs me I am not yet reputable ;).

Comment: Re your last paragraph: broadly I would disagree (e.g. wifi connection is not an issue and is better for locating), however it actually gives me a promising idea: there could be a guest account and the encryption restricted to the user session. This should in theory be doable: there should already be safeguards in place for restricting memory to users.

Symantec drive enc, for example, supports "Windows single sign-on" - perhaps this is it?

Comment: Re WiFi, the system never connects unless you've previously logged into that network so pretty useless. You can get applications as you've mentioned. They run as system accounts so you don't have to have someone log in, just turning on and getting to the startup screen is enough. But anyone with savvy, once they have unrestricted access to the hardware could potentially hack it. If you do go that route, best to kill the content when it connects. Finding the perp and them still being in that location when the police arrive is so unlikely.

Comment: Well it does happen... https://preyproject.com/blog/cat/recoveries

I admit, while chances are slim, I am quite attached to my laptop. We need an inexperienced thief who is just going to use it or sell it to someone who doesn't know better either.

While the thief might well simply connect it to a public wifi him/herself, I was originally thinking of the new Skype WiFi service to increase the chance of a connection. I haven't looked into it yet, but it might be possible to have it auto-connect. It sounds like you might know of other options as well though?.. Or even preyproject might offer it.

Comment: Know the software exists, never used it. Generally, in a corporate environment as I work in, we would use a device manager of some kind. Once stolen, the device is told to auto-wipe. A system process runs early in the boot sequence and will try to connect to any network early on, if it succeeds, it gets the kill switch from the central controller which locks out all users then attempts to format the drive. Only ever seen it succeed about twice in 20 years! Though clearly others have more success. Looking at big bucks though or some complex programming.

Comment: Looks like my hope won't pan out. I don't think any encryption software is sophisticated enough to encrypt individual user data (even though processes and memory is specifically assigned to users) and admittedly the assignment in Windows might not be airtight, which is probably why this hasn't been attempted.

Symantec's PGP product page has very little information, and the video doesn't even work, but I will drop them an email just in case.

Comment: Reading a little about BitLocker. It seems the basic mode relies on Window's user access controls. This is very interesting. It seems in the basic mode with a TPM the OS volume will readily decrypt providing no tampering has been detected on boot. The rest is just down to OS user access control? Seems very risky by itself and that a PIN or USB flash drive is really a must. Well, it's a must if you are at risk of professional hackers. For me it might not be a bad solution for keeping my user account relatively secure while still enabling access to a guest account (if only I had a TPM!).

Comment: I have found what the Symantec product looks like: https://it.ucsf.edu/services/pgp/windows-symantec-encryption-desktop-pgp-install-guide

Conclusion: The Single Sign-On feature gives full decryption of the volume, not just the data related to the user signing in (user directory and user portions of the hibernation file).

Oh well, I guess I will stick with the Remote Desktop method. Somehow this feels safer than full drive encryption anyway, though at a performance cost.

Thank you again Julian for your input.

Comment: No worries, you might want to head over to the security forum though and maybe ask some specific questions about disk encryption. You will get far more in-depth answers there. At the end of the day, any PC you walk around with is a risk. The only *safe* PC is one kept in a locked room with no network access. And as the US Airforce found out, even that has it's risks.

Answer (score 0):

While in theory it should be possible for an encryption program to provide secure per-user hard-drive encryption (user directory and user portions of a hibernation file), it does not seem that any such software exists. This may be because Windows does not fully assign user memory, it is not possible to selectively encrypt data during the hibernation process, or there is no demand for such functionality (all speculation).

Therefore, if you hope to recover your laptop with software such as Prey, you cannot encrypt your hard-drive because the criminal won't have the opportunity to access the internet on the device (for example using a guest account) prior to formatting.

Conclusion: Either encrypt your drive and wave your laptop goodbye if it gets stolen (in reality, its hardware value is most likely negligible vs the data stored). Or access your sensitive data on a desktop/server using a remote access service like Remote Desktop (RDP). In fact if you keep your laptop bare, you might not even need a user password, and therefore bother with a guest account - the criminal might then be even less tempted to have it wiped.